# Java the copy of binary tree

Tags: java

Здравствуйте,помогите сделать копию бинарного дерева.Дан только корень Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Корень Node, как и любая ветка Node, - эта объект структуры, у которой есть поле (или поля), содержащие инфу о дочерних ветвях Node (иногда ещё и о родительских), и поле или поля с некоторыми данными, которые дерево собственно должно хранить.
Соответственно, имея корень, можно обойти все дочерние ветви, создавая при этом каждую ветвь заново в новом дереве. Это и будет копированием.
Обойти дочерние ветви можно с помощью обхода в ширину и обхода в длину.
Ищите в гугле, что это такое, и разбирайтесь.